# How would I respond to a message with what the user said?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot that responds to user whenever they something like "I'm bored" with "Hi bored, I'm dad!". How would I make the "bored" part be anything someone said after "I'm". Right now it's {sender} and it just says "Hi {sender}, I'm dad!" instead of my username.

Current bot code:

```
import discord
from discord.utils import get
 
# imports library resources
 
client = discord.Client()
# connects to client
 
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
    # prints in console the message when bot is turned on
 
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
      # prevents the bot from responding to itself
        return
 
    if message.content.startswith('I\'m'):
      await message.channel.send('Hi {sender}, I\'m dad!')
 
    if message.content.startswith('im'):
      await message.channel.send('Hi {sender}, I\'m dad!')
  
    if message.content.startswith('Im'):
      await message.channel.send('Hi {sender}, I\'m dad!')
 
    if message.content.startswith('i\'m'):
      await message.channel.send('Hi {sender}, I\'m dad!')
```

Answer (score 1):

In case the other reaction isnt exactly what you're looking for:

A way you could solve this is by splitting the message content slicing off the first element (or first two in case of I am, if you want to look for that too)

```
if message.content.startswith("I'm"):
      await message.channel.send(f"Hi {' '.join(message.content.split()[1:])}, I'm dad!")
```

EDIT: some " and ' problems

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks champ

Answer (score 0):

You can use .split() to separate the words by a space into a list. Then you can use .index() to find the index of the I'm in the list, then +1 to get the next word used.

```
if "I\'m" in message.content:    
    word_list = message.content.split()
    index = word_list.index("I\'m")
    if index != len(word_list):
        name = word_list[index+1]
```